# SQL INNER JOIN ON LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

Consider the two following tables. In bold the field name. Below the field name, the field content:

tableA :
**group**
ops side west
ops north area
commando alpha
backUp
admin

tableB :
**groups**
ops
commando

What I would like is to make an inner join like query. I tried the following in phpMyAdmin but it is not working:

```
SELECT tableA.group
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableA.group LIKE "'tableB.groups'%"
GROUP BY tableA.group
```

The expected result would be to have:

ops side west
ops north area
commando alpha

Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc.

Comment: I take it you are trying to do a `LIKE` comparison between tables, i.e. the condition succeeds if the group A name is found to start the group B name. Your approach won't work as you are doing a `LIKE` on a fixed string, rather than on a field - you'll need a SQL function for this. I'd check the MySQL manual in the string operations section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT tableA.group
FROM    tableB
INNER JOIN
        tableA
ON      tableA.group LIKE CONCAT(tableB.groups, '%')
```